# Which specifications seem best for tokenizing badges and trophies?

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft

I am looking to distribute badges and trophies to users of my web service.

I have an idea for a web service to distribute badges and trophies to users.

I would like to manage the badges and trophies with ethereum smart contracts, and I am thinking of adopting soulbound tokens because they can transfer ownership in the case of NFTs.

But it seems to me that soulbound token has no information about the data and only defines the association with NFT.

I have a question.

Would soulbound tokens be inappropriate for distributing badges and trophies?

Or are there other appropriate token specifications?

Thanks.

---

I have added the following:

I referred to this URL, but I thought I only had references to other NFTs and no badge data in the soulbound token.

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-5114.md

Like this...

[SBT has reference to token]-->[NFT has badge data]

Perhaps it is correct to implement SBT to work independently?

[SBT has badge data] ＃ only consists of SBT.

Would it be possible to achieve what I'm looking for by implementing the soulbound token to have badge data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Soul Bound Tokens (SBTs) are the perfect way for you to achieve your goals.

You don’t want people selling your badges so SBTs cover that up very well. Only the addresses that are approved can be airdropped the tokens (can be defined by you as the owner of the contracts).

However, considering that such badges would be a lot in number (and eventually one user might have multiple badges), using the logic behind ERC721A tokens for Gas optimization is one thing you can look into. (https://www.alchemy.com/blog/erc721-vs-erc721a-batch-minting-nfts)

When it comes to associating data with your SBTs, SBTs can be coded to have the same kind of data as NFTs (different badges can have different Metadata based on accomplishments). The concept behind dynamic NFTs can also be looked into for the same.

It all depends on what kind of functionality you want the tokens to have and the manner of minting/transferring the token to the user you want. Based on the requirements and end goal, smart contracts will be written accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
I have added my thoughts to the original message.
If you know of any, could you please let me know about those as well?